# Game of life - edges do not change

Tags: java, arrays, conways-game-of-life

I saw Conway's Game of Life and wanted to make my own. However the cells at the edges somehow don't follow the rules and just stay alive (or dead) the whole time. Does anybody know where I made the mistake?
This is my code: (I only uploaded the class where I applied the rules. If the other classes are needed to solve the problem, I can upload them as well)

```
import java.util.Arrays;
/**
 * The class Grid does the initialization of the game of life and the application of the rules. 
 * It is a 2D array of the type Cell. It saves the cells and uses a copy of it to apply the rules.
 *
 */
public class Grid
{
    public int col;
    public int row;
    public int x,y;
    public Cell [][] array; //2D array of the type Cell
    public Cell [][] arraycopy; 

    /**
     * This constructor is to create the initial generation of cells and set the state of random 20% to true (=alive).
     * @param col   the number of columns 
     * @param row   the number of rows
     *
     */
    public Grid(int col, int row)
    {
        this.col = col;
        this.row = row;
        this.array =  new Cell [col][row];
        //Loops through every spot in the 2D array 
        for (int x = 0; x < col; x++)
        {
            for (int y=0; y < row; y++)
            {
                //set randomly 20% of the cells' state to "true"
                if (Math.random() <= 0.2) 
                {
                    Cell cell = new Cell (true);
                    this.array[x][y]= cell;
                }
                else 
                {
                    Cell cell = new Cell (false);
                    this.array[x][y]= cell;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method will count the alive cells in a 3*3 neighboorhood and apply the rules of life. 
     * This method uses arraycopy.
     *
     */
    public void lifeSteps()
    {        
        //Works with a copy of the array and the cells
        this.arraycopy =  new Cell [col][row];
        for (int x = 0; x < col; x++)
        {
            for (int y=0; y < row; y++) 
            {
                this.arraycopy [x][y] = new Cell(this.array[x][y].getState());
            }
        }
        //Looping through the cells, but the cells at the edge are skipped
        for (int x = 1; x < col-1; x++) 
        {
            for (int y= 1; y < row-1; y++)
            {
                //Looping through all the neighbors
                int numNeighborsAlive = 0;
                for (int i = x-1; i <= x+1; i++) 
                {
                    for (int j = y-1; j <= y+1; j++) 
                    {
                        //In a 3x3 neighborhood the middle cell needs to be skipped
                        if ((x != i) && (y != j))
                        {
                            //Only the cells that are alive (true) are added
                            if (arraycopy [i][j].getState() == true) 
                            {
                                numNeighborsAlive += 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                //Apply the rules of life
                if ((array [x][y].getState()) && (numNeighborsAlive < 2 || numNeighborsAlive >3))  //Loneliness and Overpopulation
                {
                    array[x][y].setState(false); 
                } 
                else if ((array [x][y].getState() == false) && (numNeighborsAlive ==3)) //Birth
                {
                    array[x][y].setState(true); 
                } 
                else 
                { //stasis
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method will return the statement for the array.
     * @return  the 2D array of the type Cell
     */
    public Cell[][] returnGrid ()
    {
        return this.array;
    }

    /**
     * This method will test if everything is working well by printing zeros and ones. 
     *
     */
    public void printTest()
    { 
        System.out.println("\t"); // a new line
        for (int x = 0; x < col; x++)
        {
            for (int y=0; y < row; y++)
            {
                // assigns 1 if the cell is alive and 0 if it is dead
                if (array[x][y].getState() == true)
                {
                    System.out.print("1");
                }
                else 
                {
                    System.out.print("0");
                }
            }
            System.out.println(""); // will be displayed as colums and rows
        }
        System.out.println("\t"); // a new line
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your comment `//Looping through the cells, but the cells at the edge are skipped` could be related ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The borders are not processed, so there are always 8 neighbors.

One can handle *all* array positions, and determine the neighbors. These could be hardwired in the cell at initialisation, or - as below - determined dynamically.

For that I use an offset vector with a delta x and delta y in -1, 0, 1.

```
private static final int[][] MIDDLE_NEIGHBORS = 
{
    {-1, -1}, {-1, 0}, {-1, 1},
    {0, -1}, {0, 1},
    {1, -1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}
};
private static final int[][] LEFT_TOP_NEIGHBORS = 
{
    {0, 1},
    {1, 0}, {1, 1}
};
...
int[][] neighborDeltaXY(int x, int y, int col, int row) {
    if (1 < x && x < col-1 && 1 < y && y < row-1) {
        return MIDDLE_NEIGHBORS;
    }
    if (x == 0 && row == 0) {
        return LEFT_TOP_NEIGHBORS;
    }
    ...
}
```

Or you might be more comfortable with nested conditions:

```
int[][] neighborDeltaXY(int x, int y, int col, int row) {
    if (x == 0) {
        if (y == 0) {
            return LEFT_TOP_NEIGHBORS;
        } else if (y == row - 1) {
            return ...;
        } else {
            return ...;
        }
    } else if (x == col - 1) {
        if (y == 0) {
            return ...;
        } else if (y == row - 1) {
            return ...;
        } else {
            return ...;
        }
    } else {
        if (y == 0) {
            return ...;
        } else if (y == row - 1) {
            return ...;
        } else {
            return MIDDLE_NEIGHBORS;
        }
    }
}
```

Useful is to have a method doing the actual counting on the board:

```
int countNeighborsAlive(Cell[][] old, int x, int y, int col, int row) {
    int numNeighborsAlive = 0;
    int[][] neighbors = neighborDeltaXY(x, y, col, row);
    for (int[] neighbor : neighbors) {
        int xn = x + neighbor[0];
        int yn = y + neighbor[1];
        if (old[xn][yn].getState()) {
            ++numNeighborsAlive;
        }
    }
    return numNeighborsAlive;
}
```

So the time loop becomes simpler:

```
    for (int x = 0; x < col; x++) {
        for (int y= 0; y < row; y++) {
            int numNeighborsAlive = countNeighborAlive(arraycopy, x, y, col, row);
            ... numNeighborsAlive
```

In the game of life one could make different geometries, having above y == 0 the y == row - 1, so the world wraps around the borders.

Also feasible is to take the original board and place it in a larger grid, so the visible cells are in [1, col - 1), [1, row - 1). The invisible borders then always remain 0. Not so nice for the game of life, but other grid based games are so walled in.

```
Instead            Do             Or
x += 1;            ++x;           x++
if (c == true)     if (c)
if (d == false)    if (!d)
```